# overloading = operator for self made vector class

Tags: c++, class, vector, operator-overloading

I started writing my own vector class and got around to overloading the = operator. I have the code below for something like `somevector = someothervector`, although I'm not sure it's right, as I'm stuck on making another overload for something like `somevector[0] = 5` with which for give my vectors values.

```
myVector& myVector::operator=(const myVector &obj)
{
    myVector tem(obj.Size()); //make new empty vector of the needed size then fill below

    for (int i = 0; i <= tem.size; ++i)
    {
        tem.array[i] = obj.array[i]; 
    }

    return tem;
}
```

I have the following for an [] overload which works for reading elements of the vectors but since it's just returning the value of the element, and I'm not sure how to fix that for assignment, I think that may be my main problem.

```
int myVector::operator[](int ind)
{
    if ( (ind >= 0) && (ind < size) )
    { return array[ind]; }

    return 0;
}
```

Can some one please offer some advice on this?

Comment: Please enable and pay attention to your compiler warnings.

Comment: You never called `myVector::operator[]` in `myVector::operator=`. You would do so if you call `tem[i]` or `obj[i]`.

Comment: You should be operating on `*this` not `tem`, and returning `*this` at the end of your assignment operator. You're also operating on a temporary, and then returning a reference to that temporary, which has just been destructed when the function exits. Your compiler should be warning you about this.

Comment: Above already being said: if you make ind unsigned in your `operator[]`, you don't need to check for `ind >= 0`. Instead of returning 0 you might prefer throwing an exception.

Comment: Thanks, Steve. I checked the settings, as far as I can tell all the warnings are turned on, but I'm not seeing any for that. Going to have to look into that more....

Comment: Out of interest why are you creating your own vector class?

Comment: Ok so if I'm operating on *this then should it not have a return type since it's acting directly on the object or..? 

And it's for an assignment, but we just had like 4 short slides on overloading that left me quite confused.

Comment: @windy401 you typically return a reference to `*this` so that you can chain assignment calls (`foo = bar = baz`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to be operating on `this`, not on a temporary.

That is, you're assigning to the current object's data members

Something along the lines of:

```
myVector& myVector::operator=(const myVector &obj)
{
    // insert appropriate code here to ensure your array's capacity is sufficient
    // to hold obj.size ints

    size = obj.size;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        array[i] = obj.array[i]; 
    }

    return *this;
}
```

To enable your requested syntax (`somevector[0] = 5`) your array subscript operator has to return a **reference** to the stored object, otherwise you're operating on a temporary. If the index is incorrect you'll probably want to throw an exception if it doesn't exist.

```
int& myVector::operator[](unsigned ind)
{
    if (ind < size)
        return array[ind];

    throw std::out_of_range("invalid index");
}
```

Comment: If the array isn't big enough to hold all of obj's elements would I just delete[] array and then array = new int[obj.size, like that and then go on assigning values, or?

Comment: @windy401 yes, exactly like that.

Comment: Sweet. Thanks a lot for everything. All makes a lot more sense now.